# DataGrid - Mouse enter + leave row events

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, wpfdatagrid

I would like to subscribe to the mouse enter and leave events of a [DataGridRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

My XAML for the DataGrid looks like this at the moment:

```xml
<toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedSearchResults}" 
              caliburn:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [OpenDocument()]" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="7"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
              IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="0"
              Sorting="ResultsDataGrid_Sort">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button"></Style>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

How can I do this using Caliburn if possible, but code-behind if not?

Comment: You could set the events in DataGrid.RowStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended hooking up in the code-behind:

MyView.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{

    public SearchResultsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SearchResultsGrid.LoadingRow += DataGrid_PreparingRow;
    }        

    public void DataGrid_PreparingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Row.MouseEnter += Row_MouseEnter;
        args.Row.MouseLeave += Row_MouseLeave;
    }

    public void Row_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    public void Row_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

MyView.xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"             
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <toolkit:DataGrid Name="SearchResultsGrid" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```